# Issue starting with Slim 2

Tags: php, web-services, slim

I'm developing a web service using Slim Framework 2, it's the first time I use php. I'm having an issue with the Slim object:

There's my code:

```
require 'db.php';
require 'vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
echo 'require ok';
$app = new vendor/slim/slim/Slim();
echo '$app ok';
```

The 'require' lines are ok. But he $app line doesn't work I use the same path to the Slim.php file and also I've tryed to use this path:

```
$app = /slim/Slim();
```

The first echo is executing but the second one is not working. My ws.php file is on the same directori as the vendor folder:

```
vendor/slim/slim/Slim/
├── Environment.php
├── Exception
│   ├── Pass.php
│   └── Stop.php
├── Helper
│   └── Set.php
├── Http
│   ├── Cookies.php
│   ├── Headers.php
│   ├── Request.php
│   ├── Response.php
│   └── Util.php
├── Log.php
├── LogWriter.php
├── Middleware
│   ├── ContentTypes.php
│   ├── Flash.php
│   ├── MethodOverride.php
│   ├── PrettyExceptions.php
│   └── SessionCookie.php
├── Middleware.php
├── Route.php
├── Router.php
├── Slim.php
└── View.php
```

Is `$app = new vendor/slim/slim/Slim();` correct? I'm lost about this topic.

Solved using [Frank Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821265/frank-martin) solution:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

Instead:

```
require 'vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php';
$app = new vendor/slim/slim/Slim();
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the composer dependencies then use this instead.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\App;
```

Comment: Correction: is working with your solution. Thank yo very much!

Comment: No problem at all :)